# Doubt to solve the system of equations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I'm new in the forum. I have come here desperate not being able to solve these exercises.
In the first part, I understand that I must derive and it seems to me that by substitution I can get the values ​​of a and b. But the third equation, which is the second derivative, what variable does it correspond to?
I leave you the exercise in case you can help me

Finding a quadratic polynomial:
$p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ such that
$p(1) = 3$,
$p'(1) = 3$,
$\:p''(1) = 2$,
where $p’(x)$ and $p’’(x)$ denote the first and second derivatives, respectively.

I have managed to solve this, but I have come this far:

$p’(x)  = 2ax+b$,
$\:p’’(x) = 2a$

$p(1) = 3 \rightarrow a . 1^2  + b.1 + c =3
           = a + b + c  = 3$

$p’(1) = 3 \rightarrow    2 a . 1 + b = 3
          = 2 a + b = 3$

$p’’(1) = 2 \rightarrow   2.1 = 2 $.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are almost done. $p''(1)=2$ gives the value of $a$. Using this and $p'(1)=3$ you get the value of $b$ and $p(1)=3$ the gives you the value of $c$.

Comment: For clarity, you should have written the last equation $2a=2$. This gives you $a$. Then the previous equation gives $b$, and the previous, $c$.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative solution:**

Let $t:=x-1$. We want to find the polynomial that has the derivatives $3,3,2$ in increasing order, at $t=0$. This polynomial must be $t^2+3t+3$, or

> $$(x-1)^2+3(x-1)+3=x^2+x+1.$$